# No Team Found in Archive, Use the Signing & Capabilities editor to assign a team to the targets and build a new archive

Tags: ios, macos, safari-extension, app-distribution

I'm trying to distribute a safari web extension, which has build successfully!, now matter what i do i cant go ahead of this step

[image]

What all did i try
1. Build done successfully.

Checks

1. My apple id is part of a team which has distribute certificate
2. I have verified by bunder identifier and yes it same is same for the app in app store connect
3. I have imported the Distribution profile and attached ot and yes it shows the correct team
4. My account role is Admin & Account holder
5. All my targets have correct bundle id and correct team
6. Under accounts i have my team (admin)  and my apple id(personal team) (user)
7. Yes i have downloaded the `Download manual profiles` and `manage certificate`s many times
8. Yes under `manage certificates` my Team(admin) has both `Distribution` and `Developer` certificates
9. Yes i have deleted `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DervidedData` folder multiple times
10. Yes i have clean the build many times
But no matter what i do i cannot move ahead, im stuck at **No team found in archive**
1. Product> Archive> A modal appears (Distribute App) (click opens another modal) > (Test flight & App store || Diorect Distribution) gives the message (didn't try to other methods avaiable in the modal)
2. Click on distribute , That's it this is the error,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Solution]

After a lot of debugging, i found the solution and app is distributed successfully

The fix is:

The Signing certificate should be **Development** not **Sign in to run locally** if the build is to  publish the app instead of running it locally!